# ROS Answers SE migration: Add library

Tags: ros, library, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to add a library to my package, i create a folder lib contain my libraries, but i dont know how to modify CMakeList.txt.
can you help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233646/add-library/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really ROS specific (catkin is basically CMake), but see [catkin 0.6.18 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Building and installing C++ libraries and headers](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0